# Trying to connect php file to localhost: localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp, localhost

I've made a folder named "koleksiku" in htdocs, inside the folder are two php files. One of them was named db_connect.php and the following code was written inside.

```
<?php
$kon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$link = mysqli_select_db($kon,"perpus") or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

And the following code was written inside the second file.

```
<?php 
include "db_connect.php"; 
$query=mysqli_query ($kon, "SELECT * FROM tbperpus")or die (mysqli_error()); 
$jumlah = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
echo "<html>"; 
echo "<head>"; 
echo "<link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>"; 
echo "</head>"; 
echo "<title>Perpustakaan Kecil</title>"; 
echo "<body>"; 
echo "<font color='darkmagenta' face='Arial' size=3><b><br>Koleksi Bukuku</b></font><br><br>"; 
echo "<a href='add.php' style=\"text-decoration: none\"><font face='tahoma' size='1'>Masukkan buku baru</font></a><br>"; 
echo "<br><table  border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" bordercolor=\"blue\" bgcolor=\"white\"> 
<tr bgcolor='blue' height=\"30\"><font color='white'>  
     <th align='center'><font color='white' face='Arial' size=2>No</font></th>         
     <th align='center'><font color='white' face='Arial' size=2>Judul</font></th>         
     <th align='center'><font color='white' face='Arial' size=2>Penulis</font></th>         
     <th align='center'><font color='yellow' face='Arial' size=2>Ubah?</font></th> 
</tr>";  
$j=0; 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {     
    echo "<tr><td align='left' bgcolor='#657FFF'>";
    echo "<font face='Arial' size=1>";
    echo $j+1;
    echo"</font>";
    echo"</td>";     
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='#E8D3DF'>";
    echo "<font face='Arial' size=1>";
    echo $row["judul"];
    echo"</font>";
    echo"</td>";  
    echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='#E8D3DF'>";
    echo "<font face='Arial' size=1>";
    echo $row["penulis"];
    echo"</font>";
    echo"</td>";     
    echo"<td align='left' bgcolor='#E8D3DF'>";
    echo "<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' style=\"text-decoration: none\" title=\"Hapus\"><font face='tahoma' size='1'>Hapus</font></a>   
    <a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."' style=\"text-decoration: none\" title=\"Edit\"><font face='tahoma' size='1'>Edit</font></a>"; $j++; } 
echo"</table>"; 
echo "</body>"; 
echo "</html>"; 
?>
```

I was able to connect to http://localhost/ however when I tried the directory http://localhost/koleksiku/ it failed to connect. I'm using MacOS BigSur while other people got it to work on Windows by following the same steps. How do I connect this php file to localhost?

UPDATE: Turns out I forgot to add my root password in the php connection syntax, I’m able to successfully connect it now.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: add a database name after the password in the mysql connction

Answer (score 0):

Like aynber said, error 500 is a generic server error, you can find more if you enable your php error messages, you can do this by setting these lines of php settings php tags before the code is run:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You'll have to remove that after you've fixed the error, so that only you locally can see these errors.